# Access VBA Option Group Coding

Tags: vba, ms-access

Is there any way to write option group code (like this) more effieciently?

```
Select Case frmCity.Value
        Case 1
            Me.frmCustomersSub.Form.Filter = "City = 'Brazil'"
            Me.frmCustomersSub.Form.FilterOn = True
        Case 2
            Me.frmCustomersSub.Form.Filter = "City = 'France'"
            Me.frmCustomersSub.Form.FilterOn = True
        Case 3
            Me.frmCustomersSub.Form.Filter = "City = 'Mexico'"
            Me.frmCustomersSub.Form.FilterOn = True
        Case 4
            Me.frmCustomersSub.Form.Filter = "City = 'UK'"
            Me.frmCustomersSub.Form.FilterOn = True
 End Select
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Choose function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/choose-function-HA001228797.aspx) can help:

```
Dim cityName As String

If frmCity.Value > 0 And frmCity.Value <= 4 Then
    cityName = Choose(frmCity.Value, "Brazil", "France", "Mexico", "UK")

    Me.frmCustomersSub.Form.Filter = "City = '" & cityName & "'"
    Me.frmCustomersSub.Form.FilterOn = True
End If
```